# Ubuntu 16, backup error question first time running

Tags: backup

I am running the backup program that comes with Ubuntu and I get the following error:

```
Could not back up the following files:
Please make sure you are able to open them
/home/brenda.bash_history
```

Comment: From [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2035285), it seems you are affected by [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-actions/+bug/1000543) bug. You can adjust the rights of the folders.  Try this: `sudo chmod -R u+r ~/brenda.bash_history`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run the command `find ~ ! \( -user "$USER" -readable -writable \) -ls` and [edit] your question to include the command output? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, I'm lost.  I have copied and pasted everything about.  The first one said no such file or directory.../home/brenda/brenda.bash_history, the second one you said run the command, etc. I copied and pasted that and it gave me a bunch of stuff, surely you don't mean for me to copy and paste that here?

Comment: ok after more searching for answers I found out this file is hidden..so I now have it on the screen in my home directory, ...I guess I need to figure out how to make it so I don't get permission denied errors

Comment: How do I say this is RESOLVED!! was a simple command.